# Recovering a partition table with testdisk

Tags: linux, partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk

I'm trying to recover a partition table with testdisk. The disk contains a dual boot Windows 8 along a Linux OS. The Linux install contains four partitions: a swap partition, the `/` ext4 partition, the `/home` ext4 partition and a tiny unallocated partition. Here is what Testdisk shows after a quick scan of the Intel/PC partitions:

[image: Testdisk quick scan result]

I have no idea which are the primary bootable (*), primary (P), logical (L), extended (E) or deleted (D) partitions. I am supposed to flag the partitions which I would like to recover with one of those letters; I tried flagging all partitions as primary, but Testdisk indicates it's a "bad structure". I suppose it's because a maximum of only 4 primary partition tables is tolerated?

[image: Testdisk bad structure]

I guess my problem comes from my ignorance of *what* are primary partitions, as opposed to logical or extended partitions...

For the record, the partition table was lost at the beginning of a Ubuntu install in which I asked to replace the current Linux partition with an LVM partition. Data was not overwritten (install didn't proceed), but the partition table was lost.

EDIT:

In this question I wrongly assumed that my hard disk was partitioned using MBR instead of GPT. However, when I run Testdisk with "EFI GPT" table type, the Linux partitions are not detected:

[image: Testdisk with EFI GPT table type]

What should I do to restore the Linux partition structure in GPT?

Comment: Was this initially GPT or a MSDOS/MBR partition table? This is important to know because GPT is as different from MSDOS as boots are from gloves. GPT does neither have extend and logical partitions nor bootable flags. Since this is a win8 install both could be possible. Used your os to boot in uefi mode? The [SYSTEM_DRV] partition suggests so but it is odd that TestDisk still asks for legacy features.

Comment: You're right: my OS used to boot in UEFI mode, so I guess I was using GPT. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Presumably the your ubuntu was installed in  BIOS mode and not in UEFI mode so it wrote/modified the partition table to the MBR so you ended up with a out of sync GPT. Recovering this might be difficult but not impossible. Let me ask some further questions. The machine does not boot at all? Have you tried to boot this hdd in BIOS legacy mode from your bios? The UEFI boot menu of BIOS usually needs to be written/modified by the installer, so it knows where to look for the boot loader on the disk (this allows multible uefi bootloader) The legacy bios boot just picks the one stored in the mbr.

Comment: The machine does not boot at all. I haven't tried to boot in BIOS mode because my goal is to recover the partition table -- and thus all partitions. My Linux OS used to boot in UEFI mode because I had a /boot/efi partition.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of that? Because to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode you have to boot the live system in UEFI mode and this is not the case by default. You have to pick the UEFI mode in the boot device menu before you start the live system. One thing you could try is to look at the mbr an try to find out if it contains a valid MSDOS partition table and convert try to convert it to gpt. But I am not sure if this will work or brake things. Make a full dump of the disk before you do this. `gdisk /dev/sdX` will start the `gdisk` utility and it tells you on startup what parititiontables it found

Comment: Be sure to exit gdisk by using the `q` key, it wont write any data to the disk.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Related: if anyone is coming here looking for instructions on recovering photos and files with the companion tool, `photorec`, instead, [I wrote a full tutorial on AskUbuntu here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1464456/327339)